# Azure App Service : How to Swap Anular-config.json variables in Deployment Slots?

Tags: azure, deployment

I have created one web application in angular and backend api is build in asp.net core.
Now my clients wants to manage two deployment slots :
1.Staging
2.Production

My Requirement is when client perform swap operation from staging->production , at that I need to change one variable which is placed in /assets/config.json(in angular application).

Basically I am placing my base-url in /assets/config.json file and when angular app is loading ,in app_initializer, i am using this base url from config.json and i am performing web api call to fetch appliation specific configuration for azure active directory.

Now base-url is different for both environments.

I have placed other app configuration variables in "configuration" section in azure app service.

But now when client swap from staging to production at that time I need to change "baseurl" but i am not able to get any provision in azure configuration section for this.

If anyone knows than please help me